# Import specified values from CSV to Google sheet by ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to import specified columns from CSV file to the specified page on Google sheet?
The CSV and Spreadsheet have lines with identical IDs, but the names of columns could be different. So, the script should fill in specified columns by ID.

Comment: Yes. How about parseCsv().map?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what is parseCsv().map :)

Comment: Utilities.parseCsv().map() and please provide an example of what you're trying to describe.